# How to get nearby location such as bank, hotel and etc with google map API?

Tags: android, api, google-maps, maps, google-places-api

I have used this URL:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&type=restaurant&keyword=cruise&key=+MY_API_CODE
```

and i enabled these services in google API console :

```
 Google Maps Android API    
 Google Maps Coordinate API 
 Google Maps Directions API
 Google Maps Distance Matrix API
 Google Maps Embed API
 Google Maps Geocoding API
 Google Maps Geolocation API
```

but for the first time it worked with no problem.The other thing is when I disable and enable Google Maps Geocoding API or  Google Maps Distance Matrix API for the first time work too. know how can handle this to not have this problem in loading nearby locations? 
Any help would greatly appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Find the solution

```
Have to enable to get response

ENABLE - Google Places API Web Service
```

Comment: I add it but it has the same problem